# ios: multiple webview with multiple links

Tags: ios, webview

can anyone help me to figure of this problem please,
im trying to create multiple webview, each webview will contain different link. The way im doing now is i can create 5 webview but only contain 1 link. here is the code

```
 NSInteger i;
int xCoord = 0;
int yCoord = 0;
int webWidth = 80;
int webHieght = 80;
int buffer = 10;

for (i = 1; i <=5; i++)
{
    UIWebView *video =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord , yCoord,   webWidth, webHieght)];
    NSString *link = @"<iframe width=\"70\" height=\"70\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/BELlZKpi1Zs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    [video loadHTMLString:link baseURL:nil];
    [video setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [video setOpaque:NO];
    [scrollview addSubview:video];

    yCoord += webHieght + buffer;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are adding same link 5 times?

Comment: what exactly u r tryn ?

Comment: im trying to add 5 web view with 5 different link, but i don't know how. what do i need to do to 4 other links show up. i don't want to code the webview 5 times with different link.

Comment: u can create array with 5 links as its object n in for u can use it ... for each web view

Comment: Create one common method for creating webview and pass the frame and URL as an argument. Call that method from the loop with respective argument.

Comment: thanks for your response user968597, but can you help out with the code please, as im noob.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   NSInteger i;
   int xCoord = 0;
   int yCoord = 0;
   int webWidth = 80;
   int webHieght = 80;
   int buffer = 10;

    NSMutableArray *links = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"link 1",@"link 2",@"link   3",@"link 4",@"link 5",nil];

  for (i = 1; i <=5; i++)
 {
   UIWebView *video =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord , yCoord,   webWidth, webHieght)];
     NSString *link = [links objectAtIndex:i];
    [video loadHTMLString:link baseURL:nil];
    [video setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [video setOpaque:NO];
    [scrollview addSubview:video];

    yCoord += webHieght + buffer;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the code.

```
-(void)setWebiewDetails
{
    NSArray *UrlArray;
    CGFloat x=0;
    CGFloat y=0;
    int endOfXco = 320;// iphone
    int noofrow = 1;
    for(NSString *url in UrlArray)
    {
        [self createWebView:url Frame:CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100)];
        x+=110;
        if(x>endOfXco)
        //End of x co.
        {
            x = 0;
            y = noofrow * 110;
            noofrow++;
            // increasing rows
        }
    }
}
-(void)createWebView:(NSString *)URL Frame:(CGRect)frame
{

    UIWebView *video =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    NSString *link =@"<iframe width=\"70\" height=\"70\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/BELlZKpi1Zs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";//Customize the URL
    [video loadHTMLString:link baseURL:nil];
    [video setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [video setOpaque:NO];
    [scrollview addSubview:video]; // Based on total web views(noofrows) you need to manage the scroll view's content offset.

}
```

Comment: dear Ganapathy, as follow to your code, if i have more than 5 link, i will need to do more than 5 case?? or is there any other way to do. And also i just add "if else" statement to auto place the webview

Comment: U have mentioned 5 webview only right in the question! What u need exactly?

Comment: sorry not to tell you exact what i want. i want to add 20+ webview with 20+ links, and i need the code auto place the webview in a certain xcoord and ycoord.

Comment: Don't expect the entire functionality from SO. Try your self and seek help if you really need. Any how updated my answer. check and customize.